# Random unmoving skeletons spawning all over?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Pillars of Eternity 1 (PC, Steam, all DLC). I am doing a clean play through and recently just noticed that human skeletons are spawning in random places. They're not actually NPC skeletons -- they don't move around or attack. They're just frozen in place standing. Sometimes they're pointing (but not at anything.)

At first I saw them outside and thought nothing of it -- eg maybe something had died and the game was rendering the corpse funny. But I just entered Dyrford, and went upstairs at the Inn to warn the thief lady. After I warned her, the game did a fade-to-black as she left; when it came back, my party exited the room and found a random skeleton at the top of the stairs.

[image: Skeleton at the top of the stairs]

It's not clickable or anything. It also clearly shouldn't be there.

Another example: random "running" skeletons spawned in the great hall of Caed Nua:

[image: Two "running" skellies in Caed Nua.]

I don't recall this ever happening on my previous play-through. Googling hasn't found very much of anything, other than a bug that was patched in 2015 where hostile skeletons would spawn randomly.

**What's the deal with these skeletons?**

Comment: What a weird bug... I would suggest to post this to Obsidian forums as you may get a response from an Obsidian employee.

Comment: Do you use any mods?

Comment: Nope. Didn't even know this game supported mods until now, tbh.

Comment: I think I saw something like that. Summoned skeletons may sometimes not disappear properly, but leave a "remnant".

Comment: The thing with summoned skeletons was a bug reported in '15 and supposedly fixed. Unless someone's following me around and summoning non-hostile skeletons in non-combat situations in random inns and other locations, I don't think they're summoned